# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0$ with epsilon-delta

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Prove $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0$$ with epsilon-delta

I tried by doing: $$|f(x,y)-0|=|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}|< |\frac{(x^2+y^2)y^2}{x^2+y^2}|=|y^2|$$ but I'm unsure how to follow.

Comment: It should be $\leq$, not $<$. Anyway, after that, you can say $|y|^2\leq \|(x,y)\|^2$, which is a very strong estimate (you can even prove differentiability of this function (after you define it to be $0$ at the origin) at the origin, not just that a limit exists). You can use $\delta<\min(1,\epsilon)$ to provide a simple estimate.

Comment: @Sebastiano actually, my teacher suggested this exact solution, but I still can't get to know why from the simplification to $x^2+y^2$ you can conclude after that $\epsilon=\sqrt{\delta}$. So if you could expand a little bit on that it would be sufficient

Comment: Please do not apply the absolute value to expressions which are nonnegative.

Comment: @Aley20 It's all written in the link I sent you.

Comment: @Aley20: you need $y^2<\epsilon$ and you can enforce that $|y|<\delta$. So pick $\delta =\sqrt{\epsilon}$